# Restrict selectable image area with imgAreaSelect

Tags: jquery, image, selection, area

Using imgAreaSelect, I'd like to restrict the area that is being selected directly while selecting.

The reason behind that is that I display a graph and the image includes the legend and the axis. I want to select only the graph area to later reload the graph zoomed on that area.

So when the user is selecting an area on the image, the selection should not go outside certain bounds.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#options) tells me that you can set the coordinates of the selection area with x1, x2, y1 and y2.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that while the user is selecting?

Comment: This is just an unfinished demo - but its showing what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/oaptsj2r/